# How to Balance Quadcopter using L3G4200 and PID controll

Tags: algorithm, arduino

I'm in progress making a Quadcopter for my Microproccesor project in University. I have set up all the hardware and now I am stacking with Balancing Algorithm.
I am very happy if anyone here who used be working on this project please Give me code of this part. By the way, I use sensor L3G4200.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: "I am very happy if anyone here who used be working on this project please Give me code of this part." - that's not how this sites works. Stop being lazy and attempt your assignment!

Comment: I know that bro, but this project is just one of my subjects in University i have to pass this term, and It is not even my major. I could not give up enough time on this.

Comment: @NguyễnVănHưng Please don't knowingly post offtopic questions just because you deem it important enough to do so. Put in some effort, then ask for help when you've tried to solve it and have a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the exact sensor as you, but this code is a snippet that I've been working on. You can look at it... Maybe it could help. If it did, then good :)

```
/*

  Project goal:

  Arduino built quadcopter.



  Motor diagram:
  Legend:

  num : motor number
  ->  : clockwise
  <-  : counter-clockwise

  2  ->     <-  1
    \         /
      \  -  /
       |   |
      /  -  \
    /         \
  3  <-     ->   4

  By   : Dat HA

  Date : 2016/11/09
         yyyy/mm/dd

*/

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <Wire.h>                       //include I2C library
#include <Servo.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"                     //include another I2C library
#include "Wire.h"                       //include another I2C library (yes, again)
#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h" //include the MPU6050 library

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool dmpReady = false;              //state of the mpu6050
volatile bool mpuInterrupt = false; //some random bool

uint8_t mpuIntStatus;               //holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t devStatus;                  //return status after each device operation
uint8_t motorPins[4] = {3, 9, 10, 11};    //yaw, pitch, roll
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64];             //FIFO storage buffer

uint16_t packetSize;                //expected DMP packet size (default is 42 bytes)
uint16_t fifoCount;                 //count of all bytes currently in FIFO

MPU6050 mpu;                        //change mpu's adress
Quaternion q;                       //quaternion container
VectorFloat gravity;                //gravity vector

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Servo motor1;
Servo motor2;
Servo motor3;
Servo motor4;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); //start serial communication
  Wire.begin();         //start I2C communication

  TWBR = 24;
  mpu.initialize();
  devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(0);

  if (devStatus == 0)
  {
    mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);
    mpuInterrupt = true;
    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
    dmpReady = true;
    packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
  }

  motor1.attach(motorPins[0]);
  motor2.attach(motorPins[1]);
  motor3.attach(motorPins[2]);
  motor4.attach(motorPins[3]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void loop()  {
  //controller
  int p = analogRead(A0);
  int r = analogRead(A1);

  p = map(p, 0, 1023, -50, 50);
  r = map(r, 0, 1023, -50, 50);

  //gyro
  int motorSpeed = 50;
  int ypr[3];
  float yprFlo[3];   //ypr as a float
  mpu.resetFIFO();
  mpuInterrupt = false;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

  if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02)
  {
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);
    fifoCount -= packetSize;
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(yprFlo, &q, &gravity);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      ypr[i] = map((yprFlo[i] * 180 / M_PI), -90, 90, -50, 50);
    }
  }

  //print
  Serial.print(ypr[0]);
  Serial.print("    ");
  Serial.print(ypr[1]);
  Serial.print("    ");
  Serial.print(ypr[2]);
  Serial.print("            ");

  //motor
  int motorSpeed1 = map(motorSpeed - ypr[1] + ypr[2], -100, 200, 90, 0);
  int motorP1 = map(motorSpeed1,90,0,0,100);
  Serial.print(motorP1);
  Serial.print("    ");
  motor1.write(motorSpeed1);

  int motorSpeed2 = map(motorSpeed - ypr[1] - ypr[2], -100, 200, 90, 180);
  int motorP2 = map(motorSpeed2,90,180,0,100);
  Serial.print(motorP2);
  Serial.print("    ");
  motor2.write(motorSpeed2);

  int motorSpeed3 = map(motorSpeed + ypr[1] - ypr[2], -100, 200, 90, 0);
  int motorP3 = map(motorSpeed2,90,0,0,100);
  Serial.print(motorP3);
  Serial.print("    ");
  motor3.write(motorSpeed3);

  int motorSpeed4 = map(motorSpeed + ypr[1] + ypr[2], -100, 200, 90, 180);
  int motorP4 = map(motorSpeed2,90,180,0,100);
  Serial.print(motorP4);
  Serial.print("    ");
  motor4.write(motorSpeed4);

  Serial.println();

}
```

Comment: Cảm ơn nhé :D
Thank you, Maybe It helpful.